# CPU load over 300% Kubernetes HPA

Tags: kubernetes

I have created a simple php-apache application to test the working of the horizontal pod autoscaler. After deploying HPA with target utilization as 50% and increasing the load with the help of the following commands

```
kubectl autoscale deployment php-apache --cpu-percent=50 --min=1 --max=10

kubectl run -i --tty load-generator --rm --image=busybox:1.28 --restart=Never -- /bin/sh -c "while sleep 0.01; do wget -q -O- http://php-apache; done"
```

after 2 minutes i am observing that the target CPU utilization goes over 100%, How is this possibe for a CPU to go above 100%?

```
NAME         REFERENCE                     TARGET      MINPODS   MAXPODS   REPLICAS   AGE
php-apache   Deployment/php-apache/scale   305% / 50%  1         10        1          3m
```

Comment: Percent is per CPU core.

Comment: could you please explain @jordanm ?

Answer (score 0):

Your 300% is computed as the current avg CPU load of all your PODs divided by the requested size.
So if you request 200m and the avg PODs load is 600m then the utilization is 300%.